# Run two containers on a single host

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, docker-compose

I have a react app - client and a nodejs app - server. I want to run them on a single docker host using docker compose. Below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  
  client:
   image: client
   ports:  
    - 3002:3000

  
  server:
   image: server 
   ports:
    - 3001:3000
```

port 3002 is accessible via the browser while 3001 is not. However, when I docker log into the server container, I get no error that is causing the container to be inaccessible. Below are the logs:

```
> rest@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.16
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
express-validator: requires to express-validator/check are deprecated.You should just use require("express-validator") instead.
```

To mention, the server application is connected with mongodb Atlas. The applications run perfectly outside the containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention a react-client and nodejs-server, but are you sure that both of them run on port 3000? What kind of nodejs-server are you running?

The `docker-compose` config-file looks promising. Remember that - when trying to reach `server` from `client` - that something like `http://server:3001` won't work, `http://localhost:3001` should.

Comment: http://localhost:3001 is not working. Idk what http://server:3001 means because I was accessing http://localhost:3001. http://localhost:3002 loads well on the browser. On docker host, both the containers run on port 3000 but I'm mapping the ports to 3001 and 3002 respectively on my local host

Comment: I used a different port in my docker file and it worked.